# Developing XPages for Clusters

Tags: xpages

I am about to start a new XPage project which will be used world-wide.  I am a bit concerned because they are worried about performance and are therefore thinking about using this application in with a load balancer or a in a cluster.  I have been looking around and I have seen that there can be issues with scoped variables (for example of the user starts the session on one server and is then sent to another, certain scoped variables go missing).  I have also seen [this wonderful article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=365493C31B0352E3852578FD001435D2#AEFBCF8B111E149B852578FD001E617B) which focuses on performance, but does not really mention anything about a clustered environment.

Just a bit of extra info: concurrent users should not be higher than 600, but may grow over time, there are about 3000 users total.  The XPage application will be a portal for a two data sources (an active database and its archive).

My question is this:  as a developer, what must I pay very close attention to when developing an application that may run behind a load balancer or in a clustered environment?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024057/xpages-cluster-and-state-variables

Comment: I thought about stateless configuration, had no chance to test it tho.

Comment: I have actually already seen this one, but I found it a bit lacking.  It is helpful at the very least and put me on the track that I need to be careful with what I do, but I do not think it is even a semi-full list of gotcha's.  Thanks though!

Comment: I know, that's why it is not tagged as answered... I am looking forward to see some useful info here, hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer...but I can't fit this in a comment.

We faced a very similar problem.

We have an xpage SPA (Single Page Application) application that has been in production for 2-3 years, with variable user load up to 300-400 concurrent users who login for 8 hr sessions, we have 4 clustered Domino servers, 1 being a "workhorse" running all scheduled jobs, and 3 dedicated HTTP servers.

We use SSO in Domino and the 3 HTTP servers participate, so a user only has to authenticate once and can access all HTTP servers.  We use a reverse proxy, so all users go to www.ourapp.com but get redirected to servera.ourapp.com, serverb.ourapp.com, etc., once they get directed to a server, the rev proxy issues a cookie to the client.  This provides a "sticky" session to whichever server they have been directed to, and rev proxy will only move them to a different server if the server they are on becomes unavailable.

We use "user" managed session beans to store config for each user, so if the user moves server, if the user's bean does not exist, it will be created. But they key point is: because of sticky session, the user will only move if we bring a server down or the server was to fail.  Since our app is a SPA, a lot of the user "config" is stored client side, so if they get booted to a different server (to the user, they are still pointed to www.ourapp.com) nothing really changes.

This has worked really well for us so far.

The app is also accessed by an "offline" external app, it points to the rev proxy (www.ourapp.com), but we did initially run into problems because this app was not passing back the Rev Proxy "sticky" cookie token, so 1 device was sending a request to proxy which got routed to server A, then 1 sec later to server B, then A..B..C, all sorts of headaches...since the cluster can be a few seconds out of sync, if sending requests to same doc...conflicts.  As soon as we got the external app to pass back rev proxy token for each session, problem solved.

The one bit of your question I don't quite understand is: "...The XPage application will be a portal for a single database (no replicas) and an archive database (no replicas). "  Does that mean the portal will be clustered, but the DB users are connecting to will not be clustered?

We haven't really coded any differently than if app was on 1 server, since the user's session is "stuck" to one server.  We did need persistent document locking across all the servers.  We initially used the native document locking, but $writers does not cluster, so we had to implement our own...we set a field on doc so that "lock" clustered (we also had to then implement s single lock store...sigh, can talk about that another time).  Because of requirements, we have to maintain close to 1 million docs in 3 of the app databases, we generate huge amounts of audit data, but we push that out to SQL.

So I'd say this is more of an admin headache (I'm also the admin for this project, so in our case I can confirm this!) than a designer headache.

I'd also be interested to hear what anyone else has to say on this subject.

Comment: By "$writers does not cluster" do you mean the problem when the master lock server is down?

Comment: No.  We have an icon we display in view grids to users, a little padlock displays if doc is locked by another user, this needs to display on all cluster servers. Using native Domino doc locking, lock a document on cluster server A (lets say it is the master lock server), the field gets set, padlock icon appears.  Now go to cluster server B, have a look at doc properties, there will be no $writers field.  It only gets set on the lock server.  So now on server B I can't display easily in a "view" that doc is locked.

Comment: ... If the lock server goes down you start getting unacceptable delays when locking\ unlocking.

Comment: Instead of checking the item you are supposed to use `.getLockHolders()` or the formula equivalent. I believe those will work. If you allow provosional lock it should lock also when master lock server is down.

Comment: That is fine on an individual document, but I'm talking about displaying a "view".  We render everything via JSON, when get get data to display in a grid, we could be retrieving a number of docs, we need this to happen as quick as possible, often we do not "touch" the NotesDocument, we are reading from a NotesNavigator, so we are reading directly from the view...so you need some property on the document that can be displayed thru a view.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Basically, I was trying to say that this one XPage application is acting as a front end to two different data sources.  I will edit the question to make this clearer.